# EF 4.3.1 Migrations - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server-2000, backwards-compatibility, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I am getting the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" when I'm trying to get my database versioned by EF migrations. The problem is the date string that EF generated ('2012-03-21T18:23:13.525Z') for new migration script entries is not supported by my version of MS Sql Server (Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit)). Is this a bug? Is there a work around?

```
CREATE TABLE [__MigrationHistory] (
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK___MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
)
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_MS_marksystemobject '__MigrationHistory'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
INSERT INTO [__MigrationHistory] ([MigrationId], [CreatedOn], [Model], [ProductVersion]) 
VALUES ('201203210144184_init', '2012-03-21T18:23:13.525Z',  0x33, '4.3.1');
```

**EDIT**

Nevermind. This has nothing to do with EntityFramework. If my SQL Server database is configured to be backwards compatible to SQL Server 2000, it won't accept that date format. I guess unless I can get EF to output it's date string in another format (or get SQL Server to both be backwards compatable to 2000 and still understand the EF date string), I won't be able to use EF migrations with my database :-(. Please let me know if someone has worked out a way to use EF with a database with compatibility level SQL Server 2000.

Comment: I think EF doesn't officially support SQL Server 2000 and its compatibility level at all so the option is migrating your database to newer supported version.

Comment: Yeah, keeping the compatibility mode on a lower version prevents the database from using newer features of the sql server instance. Luckily, I convinced IT to switch compatibility mode to SQL Server 2008 (the database had already been migrated to SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this question has an answer, the answer is:

Switch the SQL Server database compatibility mode from SQL Server 2000 to at minimum SQL Server 2005 and the issue with the date string parsing will go away.

Comment: Mine was set to SQL Server 2008 and still exhibited the problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you still want to pass in a Date you can use the `defaultSqlValue` optional parameter with a valid SQL DateTime. For example:

```c#
public partial class AddTransactionDate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        // defaultValueSql is where the magic happens.
        AddColumn("dbo.StorageTransaction", "Created", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: DateTimeToSql(DateTime.UtcNow)));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.StorageTransaction", "Created");
    }

    private static string DateTimeToSql(DateTime dt)
    {
        // Use the .Net SqlDateTime class to create a valid
        // SQL server DATETIME. We also need to wrap it in quotes
        // because EF prints out your values verbatim (e.g. you could
        // also use GETUTCDATE() etc.).
        return string.Format("N'{0}'",
            new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(dt).ToSqlString());
    }
}
```

And voila:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StorageTransaction] ADD [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT N'2012-11-26 03:06:09 PM'
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES ('201211261300214_AddTransactionDate', 'Symblr.Migrations.Configuration',
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. (After fixing the logic error: unused parameter `dt` in `DateTimeToSql()`)

Comment: This is what happens when you cobble together a sample from a test console app. Thanks @AlbertBori